# Are all O(n) algorithms O(n²) too?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, space-complexity

The formal definition of the Big O notation is that if we have a function `f(n)` (for time and space of an algorithm) and another function `g(x)`, and there are constants `c` and `no` such that `c*g(n) > f(x)` for all `n > no`, then `f(n) = O(g(n))`. But using this definition and the fact that a growing quadratic function always will surpass a linear function at some point, is it true that all `O(n)` functions are also `O(n²)`? Or better stated, is `n = O(n²)`?

Comment: O(n) functions are also O(n²) is true if `0*x^2 + B*x + C` is a [Quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation), but that is usualy considered _linear_.

Comment: Indeed, that's why we have big-Theta notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, all O(n) algorithms are O(n²), too. People are pretty sloppy with notation when it comes to Big-O. To be clear, I think it's best to conceptualize O(f) as returning a *set* of functions. Using set notation:

```
n ∈ O(n) ⊂ O(n²)
```

Answer (score 3):

Certainly.  Apply your definition with `f(n)=n`, `g(n)=n^2`, `c=1`, and `n0=1`, to see that `f` is `O(n^2)`.  All you need to notice is that when `n > n0 = 1`, we have

```
n = 1*n = n0*n < n*n = n^2
```

A similar argument shows that every `O(n)` function is `O(n^2)`.

In essence, big O is about providing an asymptotic *upper bound*.  There is no requirement that this upper bound be *sharp*; that is what big Theta is for.